# Javascript: view object in console

Tags: javascript

I have an object with deeply nested properties.

Here is the result of `console.log(myObject)` in Chrome.
[image]

But the result of `console.log(myObject.schedules)` is `{}`.

When I JSON.stringify the original object the result is `{"schedules":{}}`, which I find really confusing.  As you see above, its logging a lot more than just that.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: worth mentioning that the Chrome console for objects is of the object at the time they are opened, not at the time they are logged. so if you are changing your object later (even after logging), by the time you go to open it in the console it will almost certainly be showing you the altered object not the one at time of logging. (i sometimes find i have to `JSON.stringify`, to see the whole object as it was at time of logging)

Comment: can you share myObject

Comment: @arhoskins Please find the answers below and mark one as accepted whichever solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Do `console.dir(myObject)` instead.

> `console.dir()` displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object. The output is presented as a hierarchical listing with disclosure triangles that let you see the contents of child objects.

[console.dir() | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.dir)

Comment: Good tip, but this does not actually help with my problem.

Comment: @arhoskins Please share your object contents using `JSON.stringify()` so I can help you further.

Comment: @arhoskins What do you get in the console if you do `console.dir(myObject)` ?

Comment: The exact same thing as `console.log`

Comment: @arhoskins It works very well at my end. What browser are you using? As I said earlier, if you could provide me the `string` that you get on doing `JSON.stringify(myObject)`, I will be able to help you further.

Comment: See my answer I just posted.  The problem was something entirely different that I overlooked when posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `JSON.stringify(object)`, for more details read [this](http://dailyjs.com/2012/02/02/console/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that my object was being created via an asynch method call.  So, at the point I was `console.log()` and `JSON.stringify()`, the object was not done being created.

Comment: Then the `console.dir(myObject)` should be inside the callback of the asynch method call.